# Constructor overloading in java

Tags: java, constructor, constructor-overloading

I am getting an error with this following code fragment

The error  is : cannot reference x before supertype constructor has been called (and pointing out the statement at comment 1)

```
class Con{
    int x =10;

    Con(){
        this(++x); //1
        System.out.println("x :"+x);
    }

    Con(int i){
        x=i++;
        System.out.println("x :"+x);
    }
}
```

In the main method I have this statement

```
    Con c1=new Con();
```

I don't understand the error. Can someone explain what is actually happening here?

Comment: I means what it says.  You cannot reference x until you've called super().  Normally that happens implicitly, but since you have a `this` call the `super` call is suppressed, hence the message.  I can't think of a way to do what you want, without restructuring a bit.

Comment: What is the use of calling this() inside a constructor? Can Somebody explain? I can think of situations with parametrized constructors calling this()...

Comment: @boxed__l this() is used call overloaded constructors present in the same class.Assume you have a called constructor which takes 4 parameters, but for the 2 fields there is already another constructor to do initialization, in this case you need to use this(x,y) to call your two argument constructor

Comment: @Algorithmist :Does Compiler add `super()` to all constructors (overloaded/empty)? if so, wont' it result in multiple `super()` calls?

Comment: @Algorithmist oops it was already answered :p sorry

Comment: @boxed__l Learning should be continued even if OP accepts an answer,try to gain as much from every question.Regarding your question Yes compiler always adds super() calls if you haven't specified anything and this is valid for parametrized constructors also.If you explicitly called super() then it won't add super() from its side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When creating an instance of a class, the constructor first calls it's super class constructor to initialize the super class fields. Once all the super class constructors have run, then only the current constructor continues to initialize it's own field.

Now, when you add a `this()` call in your constructor, it doesn't call the super class constructor. This is because, the first statement in a constructor is either a chain to super class constructor - using `super()`, or a different constructor of the same class - using `this()`.

So, you can't pass the field in `this()`, because the field is isn't initialized yet. But it doesn't really make sense, why you are trying to do something like that?

Remember, the compiler moves the field initialization code inside each constructor of your class. So, your constructor is effectively equivalent to:

```
Con() {
    this(++x); //1

    // This is where initialization is done. You can't access x before it.
    x = 10;
    System.out.println("x :"+x);
}
```

This is true even with `super()` call. So, the below code will also give you the same error (considering `Con` extends another class with a parameterized constructor):

```
Con() {
    super(++x); //1
    System.out.println("x :"+x);
}
```

Comment: since I don't extend any class can we say super class constructor to the parameterized constructor?

Comment: @chathura2020. When your class don't extend any class, you need to call the `Object` class 0-arg constructor, using `super()`.

Comment: @chathura2020. All your classes extend at least one class. So, you can't say, your class doesn't extend any other class. If it doesn't do it explicitly, `Object` class is implicitly the super class.

Comment: super(++x); doesn't work because Object class does not have a paramterized constructor :). any ways gr8 answer

Comment: @RohitJain : in the above code, if we use "static int x=10;" , then it compiles fine. That means the static variable is initialized before calling the super class constructor. So the order is like this -> Initialize static var(loading class Con), initialize super class, initialize sub class. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @chathura2020. Static fields are initialized when you load your class for the first time. So, when you create an instance of your class, the static field is already initialized when you are inside the constructor. So, yes in a way, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

```
Con(){
    this(++x); //1
    System.out.println("x :"+x);
}
```

At this very moment, `Con` does not yet exist. It first instantiates by calling the other constructor. That means that `x` does not exist yet (it is created as soon as the other constructor instantiates). So you can't reference it yet.

If you really need to reference it, you have to use a static variable

```
private static int x = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

First call inside a constructor can only be `this()` or `super()` , if their is none of them then compiler automatically insert a call to super but in your constructor you called other constructor by using this() . basically whenever you **construct** an object the superclass is first initialized then the subclass's members gets initialized.So you can not refer to uninitialized members as they gets initialized after superclass's members and superclass itself.